# Recurrence in two variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Anyone know how to solve the following recurrence relation in two variables:
$$
f(x,y) = b f(x-1,y) + c f(y,x-1), \qquad 
\begin{cases}f(x,0) = b^{(x-1)} \\
f(0,y) = 0 \end{cases}
$$
(Note: repost of a post I asked yesterday with the correct formulas.)

Comment: is it $f(x,0)=b^{(x-1)}$? If so, please correct it.

Comment: Also $f(0,0)$ is ambiguous, $f(0,0)=0$ or $f(0,0)=b^{-1}$ or ...